# typeorm migration:generate can't detect removed files from entities directory

Tags: database-migration, typeorm

In Typeorm, migration: generate works fine when I create a new entity file or when I add a new column to the existing entity. But when I delete any entity file from the entities folder, it cannot detect it. For my case this is `src/models/*.ts`

Comment: Have you tried removing your build folder and rebuild from scratch? Typescript won't delete files from the build folder if their parent TS file has been deleted.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a wanted behaviour. What you want is a match between entity and table, when the entity is deleted TypeORM should generate a migration file where the table will be deleted. But there are often tables which have no entity representation, but should not be removed.
In your case you need to manually create an empty migration file `typeorm migration:create -c default -n DropTable` and drop the table.

Comment: From the context of the question, it seems for me he is using auto model sync and not migrations.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, the title clearly says migration:generate. But I will update my answer if that's the case.

Comment: I had the same problem, the bug is reported on Github https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7814. My solution was the one proposed by @JudgeFudge, create the migration manually, but you can copy the rollback code for the table you want to delete from the previous migrations and that's enough.